# AngleSharp parsing - Tables and duplicate label/value data names

Tags: c#, html-parsing, html-agility-pack, anglesharp

```
<tr><td class='separator' style="background-color:#000000;" colspan = '2'></td></tr>

<tr><td colspan='2' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#00C4C4;">Id</td></tr>

<tr><td class='label' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#FFFFFF;">1</td>

<td class='value' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#00FF00;">Pq</td></tr>

<tr><td class='label' style="border-color:#000000;background-color:#FFFFFF;">1</td>

</tr>
```

Tring too parse the above code in to key pairs and a data set struct or class.  I have been trying Dictionary and List, but get duplicate errors.  I have not tri

Id
2
Pq
3
ed the HTML-agility-pack unsure to which is the most supported solution at this time.

```
 var tableElement1 = document.QuerySelectorAll("table > tbody > tr");

                var TdDataR1 = tableElement1.Select(m => m.TextContent);

 
            var ListTdDataCssSelector = document.QuerySelectorAll("td");


            var TdData = ListTdDataCssSelector.Select(m => m.TextContent);

            var ListLabelDataCssSelector = document.QuerySelectorAll("td.Id");

            var LabelData = ListLabelDataCssSelector.Select(m => m.TextContent);


            var ListValueDataCssSelector = document.QuerySelectorAll("td.Pq");

            var ValueData = ListValueDataCssSelector.Select(m => m.TextContent);       

           
            var numbersAndWords = LabelData.Zip(ValueData, (ne, w) => new { LabelData1 = ne, ValueData1 = w });


            foreach (var nw in numbersAndWords)

            {

                // Adding key/value pairs

                // in the Dictionary

                // Using Add() method

               My_dict1.Add(nw.LabelData1, nw.ValueData1); //same key added error

            }
```

Can you help with duplicate key errors and/or point me in the correct direction for collecting the data in to unique locations.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.